# I have a button I need to turn color on fist click and change back to original color on second click

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom-events

I can get the button change color on first click but not on second click. Not sure how to execute. Console log to true as expected.

```
        var clicked = true,

            button = document.getElementById("buttonProps");

        button.addEventListener("click", function () {

            if (clicked) {
                this.style.backgroundColor = "skyblue";
            } else {

                this.style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
            }

        });
        console.log(clicked)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to toggle the clicked variable

```js
var clicked = true

button = document.getElementById("buttonProps");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {

  if (clicked) {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "skyblue";
  } else {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
  }
  clicked = !clicked

});
console.log(clicked)
```

Comment: Thanks @Jacob. I've not seen this. Do you know of a link where this toggle is described so I can learn more?

Comment: It is one of the most commonly used ways to toggle a boolean. Don't know if there is a link describing it. Are you wanting to know how it works? or why I used that instead of other options?

Comment: Yeah, thanks @Jacob would love to know how it works.

Comment: It just takes advantage of boolean properties. It assigns the inverse of the current value of the variable. Eg if clicked was `false`. `!clicked` will evaluate to true. I don't want to sound rude, but if you don't know how that works, I would recommend watching some tutorials on boolean logic and short circuit operators. As it will help a lot when it comes to simplifying if statements.

Comment: Not rude - appreciate the help @Jacob. That all makes sense.